# Is it ok to talk to be wife before marriage?

Tags: nikah

Is it ok, to talk to fiance? I been engaged and i am not into talking with her because i believe its a way of giving a confidence before marriage but people around me insist on saying to talk to her as she is engaged to you? What does islam says about talking to your fiance before Marriage/Nikkah?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as there is a Mahram with you there is no problem. A Mahram is needed so that both of you are not alone because when a girl and a boy are alone with each other, there is a third person present there and that third person is Shaytan. He will tempt you to do haram.

Umar Ibn al-Khattab narrated that :

> The Prophet (saws) said, "Whenever a man is alone with a
>   (non-mehram)woman, the Shaytaan makes a third." [Al-Tirmidhi Hadith
>   3118]

Comment: the hadith you quoted is for a man and a woman being alone. How does it relate to two engaged people talking to each other?

Comment: Two engaged people are not Mehram to each other

Comment: Until your Nikah isn't complete you are not considered Mahram to each other and therefore you are 'strangers' so you have to be careful of your behaviour i.e. no flirting.

Comment: No I was watching an Islamic show where they metioned what I have written! And I quoted the hadith so I dont see how that is my view. This place is to share eachothers understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Sister, before nikah, the man is not your mahram... so all rules of non-mahram apply to him for you.. you cannot talk to him on phone,chat, or physically being there.

and there is NO concept of Fiance, engagement in islam.. Nothing makes a girl, be open to the man, unless they are both in nikah, otherwise they have no right to talk, engage with each other openly, and never alone as well..

Comment: Agree on this, and most importantly what our people in today's society does is dragging the marriage for no reason by putting something in between called engagement which is also a wrong thing to do. so, best thing is to take time as you want tofind the right partner. ones done and everything is ok get the nikah done immediately.

Comment: "cannot talk to him on phone,chat" - i do not agree with this; i have recently answered to this topic at http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/23323/6575 .